# grunt.registerMultiTask() strips out variable from a string

Tags: javascript, templates, gruntjs, task

I am writing a grunt plugin that has to deal with a template, defined in a task. The problem I have is that even before grunt.template.process(), the variables from my template are stripped off.

The options for the task look like this:

```
wrap: {
    html: {
        footer: '<script>require(["<%= filename %>"])</script>',
        src: ['templates/*.*'],
        dest: 'new_templates'
    }
}
```

And the task itself in simplified form looks like this:

```
grunt.registerMultiTask('wrap', 'Blah-blah', function() {
    grunt.log.writeln(this.data.footer); // outputs "<script>require([""]); </script>"
});
```

[Gruntfile in simplified form](http://jsfiddle.net/spliter/pgnojw4y/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grunt automatically expands templates with `<% %>` delimiters in its config **before** calling the task, see http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#templates.

So if you want to get a template string as is, one solution would be to use custom delimiters (for example `[%` or `{%`) in your config string and then in your `grunt.template.process` call (see http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.template#grunt.template.process and http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.template#grunt.template.adddelimiters)

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the idea, Xavier!